# Using Private Repo NPM Package as Dependency With Source Files Needing Compilation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, github, build, npm

Can't find a good answer anywhere. We have a private Github repo that is an Angular module and the source needs to be built (concat, minified, etc.) and put in a dist file when consumed or installed as a dependency.

Notes:

- dist is ignored, so it never resides on Github (tried tracking this, too many conflicts with several developers)
- we are currently using a post install hook to build the dependency package source (this does NOT seem like the right thing to do, also forces the project consuming the dependency package to have the necessary build dependencies)

**Q** What is the right way (or the common ways) to build a private repo npm package dependency, resulting in a dist folder with the proper built files?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. My current workaround is to check-in the compiled source into /dist of git which is definitely not what I want. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @JanTrienes as of now we are still not tracking dist. We are using npm post install still. No feel good answers yet.